# Reading last row of specific column in Excel sheet and appending more data - in PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to write data to specific column in an Excel spreadsheet with PowerShell. I would like to start below last row with data and continiue downwards. On machine I don't have Excel installed so COM won't work for me. I'm currently using `Import-Excel` to read whole sheet and used `Open-ExcelPackage` to read specific cell values.

I could do this in `CSV` file as opposed to `.xlsx` if it's easier.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Download PSExcel module from https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel Import it using Import-Module.

Then use the following code:

```
$File = "Path to xlxs file"
$WSName = "SheetName"
$Excel = New-Excel -Path $File
$Worksheet = $Excel | Get-WorkSheet -Name $WSName

$SampleRows = @()
$SampleRows += [PSCustomObject]@{"A" = 1; "B" = 2; "C" = 3; "F" = 4 }
$row_to_insert = $SampleRows.count

$Worksheet.InsertRow($Worksheet.Dimension.Rows,$row_to_insert)
$WorkSheet.Cells["$($Worksheet.Dimension.Start.Address -replace ""\d"")$($Worksheet.Dimension.End.Row):$($Worksheet.Dimension.End.Address)"].Copy($WorkSheet.Cells["$($Worksheet.Dimension.Start.Address -replace ""\d"")$($Worksheet.Dimension.End.Row - $row_to_insert):$($Worksheet.Dimension.End.Address -replace ""\d"")$($Worksheet.Dimension.End.Row - $row_to_insert)"]);
$WorkSheet.Cells["$($Worksheet.Dimension.Start.Address -replace ""\d"")$($Worksheet.Dimension.End.Row):$($Worksheet.Dimension.End.Address)"] | % {$_.Value = ""}
ForEach ($Row in $SampleRows) {
ForEach ($data in $Row.PSObject.Properties.Name) {
$WorkSheet.Cells["$data$($Worksheet.Dimension.Rows)"].Value = $SampleRow.$data
}
}
$Excel | Close-Excel -Save
```

This code adds 1 row after the last row in the selected worksheet and adds values to this row from **$SampleRows**.... I think you got the idea. if you need add more rows to **$SampleRows** array.